# Wordpress using Jupiter Theme - Page Warning

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using WordPress with Jupiter Theme. I  have just updated the Jupiter theme with the latest version. The website is working fine but there is a one-page show Warning in the location of the header. The warning is:

> "Warning: include_once(): Failed opening
> '/srv/users/serverpilot/apps/inj/public/wp-content/themes/jupiter/framework/admin/control-panel/logic/icon-selector.php'
> for inclusion (include_path='.:/opt/sp/php7.1/lib/php') in
> /srv/users/serverpilot/apps/inj/public/wp-content/themes/jupiter/functions.php
> on line 263"

When I check the location of the missing file *icon-selector.php*, there is no *icon-selector.php* located there. I have one *icon-selector.php* file from my old version, so I copy and paste the file to *…admin/control-panel/logic* this location, however, the warning is still there.

Any thought to remove the warning?

Comment: Probably a CDN issue, do you still get the warning in incognito browsing?

Answer (score 0):

It might be related to Jupiter's new control panel. However, make sure you have installed the theme and its plugin properly also it's better to contact the Jupiter author.

Comment: It's more appropriate to add this sort of response as a comment to the post rather than as an answer. You're providing help (which is great) but it's not actually an answer that will solve the problem.